# VBA - Remove duplicates which contain less information

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, conditional-statements

First question on Stack, but not my first visit!

Basically I have this huge Excel database (>24 000 rows, merged from different tables) I have been working on for weeks and now that I'm done adding new entries, I have to clean it by removing a lot of duplicates.

The array/table is structured in the following manner :

```
+---------+-------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
| Company | Name  |       Address      |  Phone      |       Email        |
+---------+-------+--------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
| Baij&Co | Steve | 458 Preston avenue |  4156854789 |  steve@baij&co.com |
```

I did search through conventional methods but they don't exactly answer my problem, such as:

- Using the "Remove Duplicates" Excel button by selecting all columns to make sure I only keep unique values
- Using the filtering method to identify the duplicates and then remove them.

However, my goal is to remove the duplicates for which the given row(s) contains the minimal amount of information, as shown in this example:

```
+--------- +-------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
| Company  | Name  |       Address      |  Phone      |       Email        |
+--------- +-------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
| Baij&Co  | Steve |     (blank)        |  4156854789 |  steve@baij&co.com |
| Baij&Co  | Steve |     (blank)        |  (blank)    |  steve@baij&co.com |
| Baij&Co  | Steve | 458 Preston avenue |  4156854789 |  steve@baij&co.com |
```

Here, I would like to **remove the 1st AND 2nd row** as they contain less information (missing address & phone entry) about the same contact.
Does it makes sense..?

I only know the basics of VBA (like creating a userform to add a new contact and fill out the entered information in the right cells) but I struggle with advanced algorithms.

I just know the VBA related function cannot be customized, apart from selecting the columns in which I want to remove the duplicates :

```
Sheets("Database").Range("ContactsTable").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1:15, Header:=xlNo
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sort the data first so the blanks go to the bottom then choose only 1 or two columns on which to test for duplicates.

Comment: You could add a column with a count of how many cells are populated for each contact, then sort on contact and count (descending) then remove dups on contact.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fellas!

So I followed @Tim Williams 's suggestion (which is similar to Scott's actually) and did the following:

- I realized that email addresses were the unique identifier (or primary key) and I have to delete rows that don't contain any (as it becomes useless to have a contact file without contact information).
- I added a column named "Count" and inserted the following formula:

  =COUNTIF(N:N; N2)

--> Here, "N:N" is the column containing all email addresses. "N2" being the first cell.

- I then sorted the table by descending order on the newly "Count" column to have the most occurrences first.
- Then used the "Remove Duplicate" Excel tool and selected the email address column.

As a result, 10 000 rows have been removed (out of 24 000). One thing for sure is this table contains now unique contact files based on the email address. However, I will never know for sure if the most filled row was kept for each contact sadly (unless I spend days comparing both databases, row after row).

Problem solved I guess! Although I would be interested in a VBA-script to do the same (to learn on the algorithm aspect) if anyone knows anything about it :-)

Thanks again!